# jQuery illegal character showing up when trying to add jQuery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

The illegal characters seem to be in Japanese? How did this happen?
here is [my blank html](http://tomgolan.com/Toms/index.html) with jQuery/bootstrap included, firebug gives me:

> illegal character line 1 jQuery..min.js
>
> ...潡琨昮捳猨愬挫扸孥崩⥼簰⤻牥瑵牮⁤⬢灸≽晵湣瑩潮⁢漨愩筶慲⁢㵣⹣牥慴故汥浥湴⠢摩瘢⤻扨⹡灰敮摃桩汤⡢⤬戮楮湥版呍䰽愮潵瑥版呍䰻牥瑵牮⁢⹦楲獴䍨楬摽晵湣瑩潮⁢渨愩...

Comment: I'd start by adding in all the necessary tags like a doctype and a closing head tag.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftomgolan.com%2FToms%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @j08691 neither did that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server response begins with 2 "strange" characters before the DOCTYPE declaration ([U+02C7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron) and [U+02DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogonek))

Comment: They are still there - either your text editor or the server itself must be adding them... try uploading the same file to a different server or writing a new file with a different editor

Comment: It's probably the editor: if I open index.html in mine (textmate) I don't see anything strange - using cat from the command line however prints two question marks (un-displayable chars) before <!DOCTYPE

Comment: Try rewriting a new .html file from scratch